# Why style targettype has to be rebinded back to the original properties?

Tags: wpf, targettype

I am referring to the code block [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/), on Data triggers

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Styles.StyleDataTriggerSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="StyleDataTriggerSample" Height="200" Width="200">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <CheckBox Name="cbSample" Content="Hello, world?" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontSize="48">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbSample, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes!" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

To me, from programming language design point of view, the line `<Style TargetType="TextBlock">` is completely unnecessary, because it is already nested inside the `<TextBlock>`, so of course whatever setter property should be applied to the `TextBlock` type. So why need the line `<Style TargetType="TextBlock">`?

Can `<Style TargetType>` be of other type except `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why need the line ?

A Style may be defined as a resource, i.e. not inline, and if doesn't have a `TargetType` specified, how is the XAML parser supposed to be able to parse it and set the properties specified by the setters? It can't. Or at least it doesn't.

Just because you *can* define a `Style` inline you are still creating an instance of the exact same class that may be used as a (global) resource and then setting a `TargetType` is indeed required.

> Can  be of other type except TextBlock?

No, apart from a type that is derived from `TextBlock`. If you specify another type you will get an exception at runtime when the BAML (the compiled XAML) is parsed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use any class `TextBlock` derives from (for example `FrameworkElement`).

If you implement your own `CustomizedTextBlock` for example you are able to use styles defined for `TextBlock` in your project.

You find an example for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889382/cellstyle-based-on-rowstyle-in-wpf/41037320#41037320).

Comment: *You could use any class TextBlock derives from*--- on what?

Comment: A `class CustomizedTextBlock:TextBlock` could use a `Style` with `TargetType="TextBlock"` (for example...). And `TextBlock` itself derives from `FrameworkElement`. So you could use `TargetType="FrameworkElement"` for your `TextBlock Style`. But I can't see an effort for simple `TextBlock`...